# Even-only hexagonal grid generator for python

Tags: python, hexagonal-tiles

I'm trying to make an ["even only" hex grid in Python.](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Hexagonal_Tiles)

The expected output is

```
[[(0,0), (2,0), (4,0), (6,0)],
 [(1,1), (3,1), (5,1), (7,1)],
 [(0,2), (2,2), (4,2), (6,2)],
 [(1,3), (3,3), (5,3), (7,3)]]
```

I was tinkering with this:

```
>>> [[(x,y) for x in range(7)[::2]] for y in range(4)]
[[(0,0), (2,0), (4,0), (6,0)],
 [(0,1), (2,1), (4,1), (6,1)],
 [(0,2), (2,2), (4,2), (6,2)],
 [(0,3), (2,3), (4,3), (6,3)]]
```

But the next place I went from there throws an exception:

```
>>> [[(x,y) for x in xrange(y % 2, 6 + (y % 2))[::2]] for y in range(4)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing it is the following:

```
[zip(range(i % 2, 8, 2), (i,) * 4) for i in range(4)]
```

Swapping out `range` for `xrange` in this code snippet will not break it. Using the optional step argument on `range` is better than getting a full range and slicing it.

---

**Explanation of why slicing xrange failed:**

In Python 2.x, calls to`xrange` return a special type of xrange object, while calls to `range` return ordinary Python lists:

```
>>> xrange(10)
xrange(10)
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The `xrange` version crashed because you can't use slice-syntax with the `xrange` objects:

```
>>> xrange(10)[::2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'
```

But you *can* do it with `range`, since `range` returns a list which supports more operations:

```
>>> range(10)[::2]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Still, rather than slicing the returned list from range with a step, I would recommend just using the optional step argument that will work with both range and xrange!

Answer (score 0):

In posting the question, I worked out the generator I wanted:

```
>>> [[(x,y) for x in range(8)[y % 2::2]] for y in range(4)]
[[(0,0), (2,0), (4,0), (6,0)],
 [(1,1), (3,1), (5,1), (7,1)],
 [(0,2), (2,2), (4,2), (6,2)],
 [(1,3), (3,3), (5,3), (7,3)]]
```

I don't, however, know why the `xrange` version was crashing.